# html5 $locationProvider work fine on grunt serve but not working in grunt build

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, angular-ui-router, yeoman-generator

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` works fine when i ran `serve` using `grunt`.
but doesn't work with `grunt build` and show error in `console` `unexpected syntax error <`

Comment: that error probably means that you're either requesting json or javascript from a server but a html page is being returned, this usually happens when html5 mode is switched on and your web server redirects all 404s to index. This might make sense because on `grunt serve` it's possible redirecting to index is switched on, but whatever you're hosting it on has that on. Unfortunately we can't tell what `grunt serve` does unless you show us your `Gruntfile`

Comment: @DanPantry:thank you i'll check maybe it's possiable

Comment: No.Its not working here is my grunt file.
https://jsfiddle.net/saqibrizwan/70wx2mfo/

Comment: @DanPantry: check my grunt file i have uploaded on this link https://jsfiddle.net/saqibrizwan/70wx2mfo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are deploying on sub-domians like www.test.com/test so you have to mention /test on base tag

thats it!